# When should I use UNSIGNED attribute for a column exactly?

Tags: mysql, sql, unsigned-integer

Based on documentation, `UNSIGNED` columns doesn't accept negative numbers. So is that mean should I use `UNSIGNED` attribute for each column which always is containing positive or null values?

Suppose this table structure:

```
// vote
+----+---------+---------+-------+------------+----------+
| id | id_post | id_user | value | code_table |   time   |
+----+---------+---------+-------+------------+----------+
```

In table above, all columns are null or positive except `value` column. So should I set `UNSIGNED` attribute for all columns except `value` column? Am I right? Or using `UNSIGNED` attribute is based on another parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that all the columns except the `value` column is going to contain positive values then yes you should set it as `UNSIGNED`. Using UNSIGNED attribute is based only on this parameter as what value you expect in your column. Also to note that UNSIGNED ranges from 0 to n wheras SIGNED ranges from about -n/2 to n/2.

On the side of memory both signed and unsigned types take the same memory space **(4 bytes for INT).**

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNSIGNED` attribute based on the values you will store in the column.

The IDs, for example, are usually unsigned values (this is just a convention, nothing prevents you have negative ID values).

On the other hand, an `age` column will always contain positive values and the `UNSIGNED` value fits well for it.